# Passing Array Parameter to SQL command

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7

In Python 2.7, I can do this pass a parameter to an sql command like this:

```
cursor.execute("select * from my_table where id = %s", [2])
```

I can not get the array equivalent working like this:

```
cursor.execute("select * from my_table where id in %s", [[10,2]])
```

Obviously, I can just do string formatting, but I would like to do a proper parameter if possible. I'm using a postgresql database if that matters.

Comment: `I would like to do a proper parameter if possible` - what do you mean by that?

Comment: What's wrong with `"select * from my_table where id in (%d,%d)", [10,2])
`?

Comment: the list isn't fixed size. also %d works with regular python string formatting, but it doesn't work in this context.

Comment: Why do you use an array, and not a tuple, like this : `([10,2],)` ?

Answer (score 7):

```
cursor.execute("select * from my_table where id = ANY(%s);", [[10, 20]])
```

See [note](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#lists-adaptation). To use `IN` see [section below](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#tuples-adaptation).

```
cursor.execute(cursor.mogrify("select * from my_table where id in %s",
                              [tuple([10, 20])]))
```

Comment: The reason being that the `IN (1,2,3)` doesn't feature an array anywhere but rather a literal set of values.

Comment: For whoever happens to land here: I actually needed to add a comma after the list `...[tuple([10, 20],)...` to make it work. 

See also accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671702/passing-list-of-parameters-to-sql-in-psycopg2