# Read multiple lists from python into an SQL query

Tags: python, sql, amazon-redshift

I have 3 lists of user id's and time ranges (different for each user id) for which I would like to extract data.  I am querying an AWS redshift database through Python.  Normally, with one list, I'd do something like this:

```
sql_query = "select userid from some_table where userid in {}".format(list_of_users)
```

where list of users is the list of user id's I want - say (1,2,3...)

This works fine, but now I need to somehow pass it along a triplet of (userid, lower time bound, upper time bound).  So for example ((1,'2018-01-01','2018-01-14'),(2,'2018-12-23','2018-12-25'),...

I tried various versions of this basic query

```
sql_query = "select userid from some_table where userid in {} and date between {} and {}".format(list_of_users, list_of_dates_lower_bound, list_of_dates_upper_bound)
```

but no matter how I structure the lists in format(), it doesn't work.  I am not sure this is even possible this way or if I should just loop over my lists and call the query repeatedly for each triplet?

Comment: does `between` even work with lists in sql?

Comment: What package are using to connect to redshift?

If `psycopg2` check out this QA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671702/passing-list-of-parameters-to-sql-in-psycopg2 which details how to populate a SQL `IN` expression. However, you should note that required type is a tuple, not a list.

However, as others have pointed out in the comments, passing multiple elements into either side of the `BETWEEN` expression (as list, tuple, or otherwise) is nonsensical. Consider executing multiple `SELECT` statements, possibly concatenated by some kind of `UNION`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

suppose the list of values are something like following:

```
list_of_users = [1,2], 
list_of_dates_lower_bound = ['2018-01-01', '2018-12-23']
list_of_dates_lower_bound = ['2018-01-14', '2018-12-25']
```

the formatted sql would be:

```
select userid from some_table where userid in [1,2] and date between ['2018-01-01', '2018-12-23'] and ['2018-01-14', '2018-12-25']
```

This result should not be what you thought as is, it's just an invalid sql, the operand of `between` should be scalar value.

I suggest loop over the lists, and pass a single value to the placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

You can select within a particular range by using

```
select col from table where col between range and range;
```

In your case it may be

```
select userid from some_table where date_from between yesterday and today;
```

or even

```
select userid from some_table where date_from >= yesterday and date_from <= today;
```