# psycopg2 sql injection for: WHERE col IN ( 'val1', 'val2' , 'val3')

Tags: psycopg2, sql-injection

I want to allow my app user to look in my database for people living in countries of its choice. He can pass an array of countries to an api endpoint and receive corresponding people.

I do the following query in my backend:

```
...
from psycopg2 import sql
...

query = "SELECT * FROM contact WHERE country IN ('{}');".format("', '".join(query["countries"]))
cursor.execute(query)
```

How can I use `sql.SQL` and `sql.Literal` to avoid sql injection ? I do not succeed to manage the `'`

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8671854/1467914

Comment: You don't need to use `sql` you need to read [Passing parameters](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries) and [Python adaption](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types). That will solve this issue and many others.